# What is the equivalent of Ansible's delegate_to in Puppet

Tags: puppet, ansible

When using the Ansible provisioner, the delegate_to: ip_address can be used to execute actions on the machine that originally invoked ansible (the host) instead of the guest.

When using Puppet, what would be a similar equivelent?

Answer (score 2):

Functions in a manifest are executed on the puppet master (if using agent). Resources are evaluated by the agent on the node. Note that this happens in stages, so functions are all called when the manifest is compiled and resources happen later after the compiled catalog is sent to the agent. Catalog caching can also prevent functions from being called on ever invocation of the puppet master.

Answer (score 2):

Puppet implements a client / server paradigm (agent / master in Puppet jargon).  I'm not sure whether that maps cleanly to Ansible's guest / host.

Nevertheless, Puppet DSL functions run on the master during catalog building.  You can write custom DSL functions relatively easily, and you can run arbitrary commands (within the capabilities of the relevant user) via the built-in `generate()` function.

Additionally, if the master manages itself (which is common) then you can use exported resources to cause resources to be defined during building of any node's catalog that can later be collected and applied to the master.

Puppet does not provide any means, however, to cause code to run on the master as part of the process of the agent applying a catalog to a different node.